# R cannot find g77

Tags: r, compiler-errors, package, fgarch

I am trying to install from Cran the R package "fGarch", using `install.packages('fGarch')` I am on Ubuntu, I have r-base-dev and r-base-core installed.
But the install fails because:

```
77 -fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-ttHamR/r-base-4.0.2=. -fstack-protector-strong  -c dist.f -o dist.o
/bin/bash: 77: command not found
/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:190: recipe for target 'dist.o' failed
make: *** [dist.o] Error 127
```

I have gfortran, gcc, g++. I also have something called "f77".

```
which f77
/usr/bin/f77
```

But nothing simply called "77". I do not understand what R is trying to call with "77".

I also installed the package from apt-get, but this then returns an error in R saying the version is too old and I should reinstall it.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Just to make certain, you are installing `fGarch` using `install.packages('fGarch')`? What is your `systemInfo()`? (Eg. version of R, which repository are you trying to install/download `fGarch` from, and so on.). It might be useful to include these in your original question (simply edit and add this informtion)

Comment: You can do `sudo apt-get install r-cran-fgarch`.

Comment: Also, for build-dependencies, make sure you install `r-base-dev` as well as `r-base-core`.  `r-base-dev` will pull a few things in that are useful for package building.

Comment: Yes I did it with install.packages.